# opening a compressed file twice and reading using perl

Tags: perl, compression

I tried opening a .gz file twice the script got hung. Below is the code :

```
open(my $file, '-|', '/usr/bin/gzip -dc file.gz') or die $!;
...
close $file;
print "File closed\n";
system 'pwd';
print "opening file\n";

open(my $file2, '-|', '/usr/bin/gzip -dc  file.gz') or die "couldn't open file,$!";
print "File opened\n";
close $file2;
```

output:

File closed

opening file

I want to open the file and read it again. I am not able to see the print "File opened" . What might be the reason?

Comment: You are declaring `my $file` twice in the same scope, that should give you a warning. Remember to `use strict; use warnings`

Comment: `use Cwd; say getcwd;` instead of that `system 'pwd'`. [Documentation](https://perldoc.pl/Cwd).

Comment: @techie Thanks for the update, it works fine here (Ubuntu 19.10), I get the output "File opened". Is the problem independent of the file you try to unzip?

Comment: @HåkonHægland Yes it is independent of that. It is working fine now by adding --> $| =1;  in the beginning of script and adding --> print "." unless $. %1000; inside the while loop used after opening the file for the first time.